# Trouble connecting to Oracle 18c XE on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, oracle-xe, oracle18c

A few weeks ago I had installed Oracle 18c XE on my Win10 PC to test an app. Once everything checked out, we installed the same thing on Windows Server 2012r2. When connecting to SQLPlus we get an error message `ORACLE is not available`. Then after attempting startup we get `Oracle DB XE memory parameters invalid or not specified.`

I am unsure where this value is set or how to fix this issue. This worked fine on my PC and I have no outside experience of getting the database set up on a server. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this in haste after working a few hours trying to get this working. This was fixed by adding the an entry in the `listener.ora` file for the XE service instance. After this, I was able go execute the startup command in SQLPlus. I do need more help but will post my question in the DBA Stack Exchange server.